# Porque no puedo recuperar el contenido de un TextBoxt en wpf Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, xaml

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio  en WPF con Visual Studio.
cuando quiero obtener el contenido de esa caja de texto no recupero nada. 
 Les agradecería mucho si me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo.

```
<TextBox Name="txtUsuario" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0 50 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario">
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario"/>
                        <Image Margin="0,0,25,0" 
                           Source="/Resources/user_login2.png" 
                           Width="12" 
                           Height="12"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: ¿que codigo estas usando para recuperarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Muy fácil, lo que pasa con tu etiquetado XAML es que, probablemente, estás tratando de recuperar el valor de `Text`, pero el contenido del `TextBox` está en el `TextBox` que está dentro de la `Template` que hiciste y no en el "Parent", por lo cual, la propiedad `Text` del control "Parent" siempre será un texto vacío.

Lo que debes hacer es modificar la siguiente linea:

```
<TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario"/>
```

Ya que ahí está el texto que quieres.. NO arriba en el "Parent" donde debería estar, solo por si tienes dudas, con "Parent" me refiero al control "txtUsuario".

Naturalmente, la primera idea sería acceder a esa parte del control para recuperar el texto, pero eso no es lo óptimo, lo que tienes que hacer en ese caso es indicarle al `TextBox` (el que si tiene el texto, el de la linea que te indiqué) que debe relacionarse a la propiedad `Text` del "Parent", osea el TextBox en si.. eso es un simple Binding..

La linea que te indico arriba debe quedar así:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario"/>
```

El etiquetado completo sería así:

```
<TextBox Name="txtUsuario" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0 50 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Ingresa un usuario"/>
                <Image Margin="0,0,25,0" 
                Source="/Resources/user_login2.png" 
                Width="12" 
                Height="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

Y ya con eso puedes Bindear el texto a otros controles o propiedades como un `TextBox` común.

Suerte!